# fabricjs - toSVG displace objects

Tags: fabricjs

I'd like to save an SVG of my canvas, wut when doing so, it seems like some of my objects are displaced :

Here is the content of my canvas
[image: My canvas]

And here is the result of `toSVG()`
[image: Broken image]

Do you have any idea where it might come from ?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is actually a bug in v2.4.5. Until a fix is merged you should be able to use v2.4.4 without issue.

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5436

Comment: I m the author, i second that. A bug not caught from regression test slipped on 2.4.5. Or more likely i did not watch the right test page, because right now is all broken. http://fabricjs.com/test/svg_import/

Comment: thank you very much ! And @AndreaBogazzi, thank you so much, keep up the good work with this amazing project !